# Maestro workflow status block

Tags: blocks, workflows

After adding the Maestro status block to my homepage-content region, it doesn't display the status bar nor the status messages which were set in the workflow. It displays only the workflow title.

3 of my workflow Participate in Setting the Workflow Stage and Status Message yet it displays only the title of my maestro workflow.

I took time to inspect the "Maestro Insurance Site" a demo site created by nextide creators of Maestro to tales check out the html being displayed.

[image: Maestro Insurance.ca Statusbar]

[image: My Site Statusbar display]

Answer (score 0):

The reason for status bar not showing is ,
maestro validation check throws an informative error:
"The default number of stages you wish to show this workflow having" option is set to zero.

To solve this, select Edit Template button in the Template builder and set the value to the number of stages you would like to show, in my case it's 3

After update template and select validity check; error should be gone

status bar shows